# Getting NullPointerException when retrieving google's user profile

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When I am trying to get user profile after login then getting `NullPointerException` caused by:

```
09-26 06:57:50.960  19641-19641/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sanni.retrievegoogleprofile, PID: 19641
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.sanni.retrievegoogleprofile/com.example.sanni.retrievegoogleprofile.GoogleLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
            at com.example.sanni.retrievegoogleprofile.MainActivity.loginAndGetUserProfile(MainActivity.java:21)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my code snippet:

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GoogleLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

### GoogleLogin.java

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Please wait", "Loading...");

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webview);

        String googleAuthorizationRequestUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(
                CLIENT_ID,
                REDIRECT_URI,
                SCOPE).build();

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.dismiss();

                if (url.startsWith(REDIRECT_URI)) {
                    try {
                        if (url.indexOf("code=") != -1) {
                            // Url is like http://localhost/?code=4/Z5DgC1IxNL-muPsrE2Sjy9zQn2pF
                            String code = url.substring(
                                    REDIRECT_URI.length() + 7,
                                    url.length());


                            AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(
                                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                                    new JacksonFactory(),
                                    CLIENT_ID,
                                    CLIENT_SECRET,
                                    code, REDIRECT_URI)
                                    .execute();

                            write(accessTokenResponse);
                            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                            MyStocks.mLoginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            MyStocks.mMyyStocksLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            retrieveProfile();
                            Log.d("SANNI", "retrieveProfile excution finished");
                            finish();
                        } else if (url.indexOf("error=") != -1) {
                            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                            MyStocks.mLoginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            MyStocks.mMyyStocksLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            clearCredentials();
                            finish();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(googleAuthorizationRequestUrl);
    }

    public AccessTokenResponse read() {
        AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new AccessTokenResponse();
        accessTokenResponse.accessToken = mPrefs.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
        accessTokenResponse.expiresIn = mPrefs.getLong(EXPIRATION_TIME, 0);
        accessTokenResponse.refreshToken = mPrefs.getString(REFRESH_TOKEN, "");
        accessTokenResponse.scope = mPrefs.getString(SCOPE_STRING, "");
        return accessTokenResponse;
    }

    public void clearCredentials() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.remove(PREF_KEY_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        editor.remove(EXPIRATION_TIME);
        editor.remove(REFRESH_TOKEN);
        editor.remove(SCOPE_STRING);
        editor.remove(PREF_KEY_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void write(AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessTokenResponse.accessToken);
        editor.putLong(EXPIRATION_TIME, accessTokenResponse.expiresIn);
        editor.putString(REFRESH_TOKEN, accessTokenResponse.refreshToken);
        editor.putString(SCOPE_STRING, accessTokenResponse.scope);
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_GOOGLE_LOGIN, true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void retrieveProfile() {
        Log.d("SANNI", "retrieveProfile called");
        try {
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
            AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = read();

            GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                    accessTokenResponse.accessToken, transport, jsonFactory,
                    CLIENT_ID,
                    CLIENT_SECRET,
                    accessTokenResponse.refreshToken);

            Builder b = Plus.builder(transport, jsonFactory).setApplicationName("Stockal");
            b.setHttpRequestInitializer(accessProtectedResource);
            Plus plus = b.build();
            mProfile = plus.people().get("me").execute();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome Mr." + mProfile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("SANNI", "exception occured in retrieveProfile :" + ex.getMessage().toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this why I am getting the exception.

When I debug my app the it crashing at...

```
AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(
                                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                                    new JacksonFactory(),
                                    CLIENT_ID,
                                    CLIENT_SECRET,
                                    code, REDIRECT_URI)
                                    .execute();
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Where is `com.stockal.app.components.AppRegistry.getString` called? I do not see it in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: Your question was mistakenly closed, because it is not a duplicate. But, if you request debugging help, put the minimal code here which is needed to reproduce the bug.